# QEMU RDRAND Instruction Not Supported

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu

I am trying to run a custom kernel in `qemu-system-x86_64`. This kernel requires the usage of the `rdrand` instruction early in its boot cycle, and will fail to boot if it is not supported by the CPU. I read in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860025/rdrand-instrucrtion-sigill) that `rdrand` requires at least an Ivy Bridge processor. However, when I run QEMU with the `-cpu SandyBridge` parameter (which should tell it to emulate a Sandy Bridge CPU, which supports `rdrand`), my kernel still will not boot. I have tried `-cpu Broadwell`, presumably because it is a newer CPU, but nothing changes.

Here is the assembly being run that checks `cpuid` and executes `rdrand`:

```
00025c79    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
00025c7b    movl    $0x1, %eax
00025c80    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
00025c82    cpuid
00025c84    testl   $0x40000000, %ecx       ## imm = 0x40000000
00025c8a    jne 0x25c98
00025c8c    movl    $0x2d479, (%esp)        ## 0x2D479 points to an error string
00025c93    calll   _stop                   ## This function call does not return
00025c98    movl    $0x2d4b1, (%esp)        ## 0x2D4B1 points to a debugging message
00025c9f    calll   _printf
00025ca4    movb    $0x0, 0x1b(%esp)
00025ca9    rdrandl %eax
00025cac    setb    0x1b(%esp)
00025cb1    cmpb    $0x0, 0x1b(%esp)
00025cb6    je  0x25ca9
```

Comment: As far as I can see, currently qemu does not support `RDRAND` unless you use hardware virtualization and your host cpu supports it. As a workaround you might want to look at `bochs` which does.

Comment: *...a Sandy Bridge CPU, which supports `rdrand`*  What?  Real SnB hardware doesn't support `rdrand`. (my desktop is a non-virtualized SnB, and it's not in /proc/cpuinfo).  And you just said you found out that `rdrand` requires IvB or later.  Anyway, this isn't a solution to your problem, since you say it doesn't work with `-cpu Broadwell` either.

Comment: According to wikipedia RDRand is part of the ivy brigde architecture, while on some ivy bridge versions RDRand creates an illegal instruction exception